# Calculating an integral by finding a probability density function

Tags: probability

Could anyone offer any **hints** on this question? I can't get how this relates to probability theory.

> Find the exact value of
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-2)^2e^{\frac{-(x-2)^2}{8}}$$
> Hint: construct a pdf

Comment: just use integration by parts and you are done. Also, prior to anything, the substitution $t=x-2$ simplifies a bit the expression

Comment: Do you know the PDF of a normal RV?

Comment: Is the answer is 8?

Comment: No, it is proportional to $8$, though. The PDF “part” of the integrand is missing the normalization factor.

Comment: It's "proportional" to $8$? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the pdf of the normal distribution reads

$$f(x, \mu,\sigma)= \frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}  e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$

and integrate as follows

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-2)^2e^{\frac{-(x-2)^2}{8}} 
& = 2\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-2)^2f(x,2,2)dx\\
&= 2\sqrt{2\pi} \cdot variance \\
 &= 2\sqrt{2\pi} \cdot 2^2 \\
& = 8\sqrt{2\pi}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x-2$, which implies that $du=dx$. Also, the limits of integration remain the same. The integral can then be expressed as:

\begin{equation}
I=2\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} u^{2}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{8}} \,du
\end{equation}

Now, let $z=\frac{1}{8}u^{2}$, then we can see that: $du=\sqrt{2}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Once again, the limits do not change.

\begin{equation}
I=2{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}8ze^{-z}}\,\sqrt{2}z^{-\frac{1}{2}}dz=16\sqrt{2}\underbrace{{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}z^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-z}}\,dz}_{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}
\end{equation}

Given that $\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, then we conclude that: $I=\sqrt{16\pi}$.